# Haskell nested multiline comments aren't highlighted properly

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

In a question tagged [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell), this answer:

[Hidden features of Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211216/hidden-features-of-haskell/213431#213431)

> ```
> {- inside a comment,
>      {- inside another comment, -}
> still commented! -}
> ```

The nested comments aren't highlighted the right way. Is this by-design or is this a bug?

Comment: Looking at [the source](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/lang-hs.js), it doesn't look like it supports nested comments.  I don't think prettify was designed with this in mind.